# Is it possible to use a gcc compiled library with MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, linker, iconv

I have a project that relies on `libiconv` for several operations.

I was using precompiled binaries for `iconv.lib` for Visual Studio 2008 but now I had to move on to Visual Studio 2010 and no more precompiled binaries were available.

I decided to compile it myself but as the `libiconv` documentation states, there is no official support for MSVC compilers. However, I read somewhere that `gcc` could generate static libraries that were binary compatible with MSVC compilers, as long as the binary interface remains in `C`. While that sounded crazy, I gave it a try and it actually almost worked.

I compiled it, renamed `libiconv.a` to `iconv.lib` and tried to link with it. (If this is a bad idea, please let me know).

First I encountered a link error:

```
1>iconv.lib(iconv.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___chkstk
```

After some research, I recompiled `libiconv` (in both x86 and x64 version), adding the `-static-libgcc` flag.

It worked, but only for the x64 release of my program. The x86 release always fails with the very same error.

What should I do to make this work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible because if you compile strictly as a C interface, iconv will link to `msvcrt.lib`, which is the Windows C runtime (strictly C, analogous to `glibc` used by GCC). If you built it with GCC's normal C++ compiler, it would link to `libstdc++` and also name mangle differently compared to VC++, which links to `msvcr.dll`.

In your case, [`__chkstk` is the check stack function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100775) (part of C runtime), a function that is injected into each function call to check for stack overflows. I am not sure how to resolve this a 'good' way, but you can change your build options for iconv to build with an additional compiler flag and suppress this check: `/Gs999999`

However, I have built libiconv with Visual C++ 2005/2008/2010, and software I have built on top of it worked perfectly (software used by military institutions, if you need credibility). I do remember it being slightly annoying to build using the VC++ compiler though, but it should not be too much pain.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the answer and no doubt about your credibility ;) I'm interested about how you compiled libiconv. How did you do that with the MSVC compiler ? The author of libiconv unfortunately dropped support for MSVC compilers in summer 2006. Did you built up your own Makefile for it ?

Comment: @ereOn, I'll attempt a build again and get back to you. I definitely built libiconv much more recently with VC++ (several times since 2008).

Comment: Thanks, I finally managed to do it. Not the latest version of `libiconv` because the author dropped support for MSVC, but I went back with an older one which still had MSVC support.

Comment: And once you have a halfway working gcc, you could recompile using gcc to get a fully working gcc.