# Using libraries compiled with GCC in a VisualC++ project (and vice versa)

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, libraries, soci

It's possible to use code (and libraries) compiled with VisualC++ (so with .lib extension) in a project that will use GCC as compiler (and vice versa)? Or I have to rebuild them?
I'm trying to use SOCI 3.1 libraries that I have compiled with VisualC++ in a project that has GCC as compiler, but I'm getting some errors, and I don't know why..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265639/is-it-possible-to-use-a-gcc-compiled-library-with-msvc

Answer (score 2):

You have to produce binaries for GCC using MinGW tools: reimp and dlltool. Here is MinGW wiki with complete explanation of the procedures: [MSVC and MinGW DLLs](https://web.archive.org/web/20200804202518/http://mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs)

Short example:

```
reimp -d libmysql.lib
dlltool -k --input-def libmysql.def --dllname libmysql.dll --output-lib libmysql.a
reimp libmysql.lib
```

By the way, here is related thread on SOCI users mailing list which: [MySQL Build fails](https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=30466136). Look for useful links given in the thread.