# fstream doesn't read the input Visual Studio Code but it works in Visual Studio Community

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-code, fstream, ifstream

The code below works properly in Visual Studio Community 2019, the input file opens and gets read.

When I try the same code in Visual Studio Code, it doesn't work, and returns "access denied".

I need to use Visual Studio Code.

The input file is in the `.exe`'s directory in case of Visual Studio Code, and in the `.cpp`'s directory in case of VS Community.

VS Community Screenshot:
[image]

VS Code Screenshot:
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    string word;
    file.open("input.txt");
    getline(file, word);

    if (file.is_open() == true)
        cout << "access aproval" << endl;
    else
        cout << "access denied" << endl;

    cout << word << endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure your input file is under the same directory as this file?

Comment: Whether the "Text files are in the same folder as main.cpp" is completely irrelevant. What really matters is whether the text files are in the same folder as the executable's current directory. This is something that only you can figure out, since only you know how your C++ compiler and development environment is configured.

Comment: input files are under the same directory as the executable's current directory. I was thinking that maybe somewhere in the configuration I have to define where vsc search for input files but i couldn't find that

Comment: @Adrian I question if you really understand what "current directory" actually means. The "current **working** directory" is not guaranteed to be where the `.exe` is located, or even the `.cpp` file. You should print out the result of `GetCurrentDirectory()` or `std::filesystem::current_path()` to see where `open("input.txt")` is actually searching for the file. It is probably not always going to be where you expect. Which is why you shouldn't rely on using *relative* file paths, always use *absolute* file paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give the full location of the file.
`file.open("C\..\input.txt");`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I've spent over 4 hours testing things, and I think the problem lies in the compiler you're using.

I was using MinGW64 with Visual Studio Code, and besides fstream odd behavior with detecting file, creating an fstream object erased any variable values declared before it. **MinGW64 is the problematic compiler, so using UCRT64 fixed the issue, making it behave correctly like Visual Studio Community**

I've tested this on command line (CMD / PowerShell) (with MinGW64 in PATH Environment Variable) by building the program with

```
g++ [sourceFile].cpp -o [executableFile].exe
```

and running it with

```
.\[executableFile].exe
```

and found that the problem still lies, so it's not a Visual Studio Code problem but a compiler problem.

---

According to this stackoverflow thread, [usage of MSYS2 environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68607245/usage-of-msys2-environments),
“MINGW64 is old and time-tested. UCRT64 is new. UCRT64 supports UTF-8 in file paths (MINGW64 needs workarounds). I believe neither is compatible with MSVC (for C++, could be compatible for C), but this usually doesn't matter.”

“MinGW64 uses old MSVCRY technology.”

The fact that UCRT64 supports UTF-8 file path is probably why it handles IO Streams like fstream fine while MinGW64 runs into problems, I would assume.

Comment: Blaming the compiler here makes little sense. Why should UTF-8 be a problem when attempting to open `"input.txt"` in a very simple program?